# Synonym request: [column] edition

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Two synonym requests for the price of one:

- Multiple columns

  - Source: [multi-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-column) (217 q, no wiki)
  - Source: [two-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/two-columns) (107 q, no wiki)
  - Target: [multiple-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-columns) (1659 q, wiki)
- Computing columns:

  - Source: [computed-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computed-columns) (271 q, no wiki)
  - Target: [calculated-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculated-columns) (463 q, wiki)

Comment: seen multiple of your posts today on Hot.. you're on a Meta roll with that new rep you mentioned.

Comment: The difficulty with getting synonym requests (presumably for [tag:computed-columns] to be a synonym of [tag:calculated-columns], etc) is finding the people with enough reputation in the tags to be able to suggest synonyms.  I looked; I don't qualify in either tag that has a wiki — one answer, two votes in each, IIRC.  I think the suggestions are good.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The idea is that a moderator will do it, they don't need rep.

Comment: Do we actually need [tag:row]s and [tag:column]s?

Comment: @TLama [tag:column] doesn't exist...

Comment: Yep, I know. My point is if we should create it rather than burning [tag:row].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syn's and merges:

[multi-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-column) -> [multiple-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-columns) and 
[computed-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computed-columns) -> [calculated-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculated-columns)

Needs work:

Looks like [two-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/two-columns) is mostly for specific CSS layouts but can also be [multiple-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-columns) (or not obviously relevant at all) - needs a bit of a tidy-up though (a syn./merge will just obfuscate any work efforts).